# Background Image is not getting displayed on Phone

Tags: android, image, background, resources, drawable

I am facing this annoying problem where my apps background image is displayed on the emulator but not on my Samsung S4 Active Device. I tried to execute the app in another device and it worked but i dont know what's going on with my phone. I did the Factory reset but to no avail. I am using Android studio for doing the coding and everything was working fine few days back but now i am having the problem with that particular background image when i tried another image and it worked fine in my phone.

Did anyone faced such an issue ?Any help will be appreciated as i am not able to proceed because of this problem.

```html
enter code here`
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_draft">
    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
GB

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code. The problem might be in the different versions, as `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Matter Cat for your quick reply. I will post the code but its just a png image in drawable folder and i have used the xml code, android:background = "@drawable/background_draft"  code to render the image. I tried the same code in another phone and it worked.

Comment: In that case, it mightttt be an out of memory exception, especially if a different image works fine. What exception is thrown when your phone crashes?

Comment: Phone doesn't crash, So the app gets loaded and it works but without the image. The phones i tried are both on Kitkat ( 4.4.2) version and yes i thought of the memory issue and so did the factory reset which emptied my phone but still the background image didnt show up.

Comment: Updated the XML code in the original post

Comment: The problem was with the resolution of the image. I reduced the resolution of the image and now it is getting displayed on my phone. So all good. Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

Reducing the image size fixed this problem for me also. I was trying to use a jpg that was 1080 x 1920. When I reduced it to 540 x 960 the background image appeared in my device (a regular GS4). Thanks Stack.